# Change the key after group_by result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array:

```
issues={#<Issue id: 669, tracker_id: 2,parent_id: 663,
 #<Issue id: 668, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 663,
 #<Issue id: 667, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665,
 #<Issue id: 666, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665,
 #<Issue id: 665, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658,
 #<Issue id: 664, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662,
 #<Issue id: 663, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662,
 #<Issue id: 662, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658,
 #<Issue id: 661, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: nil}]
```

If I use `group_by`:

```
 leveled_tasks = issues.sort_by(&:id).group_by(&:parent)
```

I get the following result:

```
{ nil=>[#<Issue id: 661, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: nil}],
 658=>[#<Issue id: 665, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658,
 #<Issue id: 662, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658],
 662=>[#<Issue id: 664, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662,
 #<Issue id: 663, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662],
 663=>[#<Issue id: 669, tracker_id: 2,parent_id: 663,
 #<Issue id: 668, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 663],
 665=>[#<Issue id: 667, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665,
 #<Issue id: 666, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665]}
```

I want it like:

```
{ 0=>[#<Issue id: 661, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: nil}],
 1=>[#<Issue id: 665, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658,
 #<Issue id: 662, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 658],
 2=>[#<Issue id: 664, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662,
 #<Issue id: 663, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 662],
 3=>[#<Issue id: 669, tracker_id: 2,parent_id: 663,
 #<Issue id: 668, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 663],
 4=>[#<Issue id: 667, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665,
 #<Issue id: 666, tracker_id: 2, parent_id: 665]}
```

I used `group_by level` but it gives me:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method level' for #<Issue:0xb514796c>): lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in sudo_mode'
```

for this:

```
leveled_tasks = issues.sort_by(&:id).group_by(&:level)
```

Comment: "`it gives me an error`". What error? Also, your array elements aren't valid Ruby code. They appear to be `inspect` output, but those don't result in code we can copy/paste to test. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: The error is:   NoMethodError (undefined method `level' for #<Issue:0xb514796c>):
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'

Comment: Please don't put information that is important to the question in comments. When you do that people trying to help you have to read every comment and try to figure out what goes where/when. Instead, edit your question and put the information into it as if you'd added it there initially. Don't put "Edit:" or "Update:", put it where it belongs. If we need to know what was changed we can look at the revision history

Comment: We can't duplicate your code or problem. There is no `level` defined in your object, which is why you get the error. Since you haven't given us the definition of the object we can't help you. Read "[ask]", "[mcve]", and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. Voting to close because of lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over hash keys and start fill a new one with desired output like:

```
grouped_issues = issues.sort_by(&:id).group_by(&:parent)
leveled_tasks = {}
grouped_issues.keys.each_with_index do |key, index| 
  leveled_tasks[index] = grouped_issues[key]
end
```